# How do I copy-paste in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have some text in Notes in Ubuntu Touch. I want to copy-paste them to another app. Ctrl-C doesn't seem to copy, or Ctrl-V doesn't paste (I'm not sure which). Right-click doesn't bring up a context menu. There's no edit menu.

Does the concept of a clipboard exist in Ubuntu Touch? How do I use it?

Comment: If it's anything like the other touch-enabled mobile OSes out there, holding down on a word will select it and allow you to expand that selection before copying it.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as you describe. Holding down doesn't select text. And even when I do select text using a mouse, touching the selection just deselects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many places in Ubuntu touch pressing and holding a word does select the word and bring up a context menu with options such as select all, copy etc. just like other mobile OSes. For example the Ask Ubuntu app I'm writingbthis in behaves that way.

The Notes app on my M10 does not. I'm tempted to say it's a bug.

Comment: Ah! I'm on an M10 and its the only place that I can type any amount of text so it's the only place I tried! Definitely a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With OTA-13, using the Notes app on the M10, I still can't get the option to copy the whole text. It only allows me to copy one word at a time. When I try to select everything I lose the option to copy.

One workaround I use is to switch to Desktop mode, click on the text, click on select all, and then on copy.